# What is the equivalent to D's taskPool.parallel() in C++

Tags: c++, d

Is there an equivalent feature to D's *parallel()* from the *std.parallelism* module in C++?

Comment: C++ doesn't currently have a built in threadpool, currently this is something you'd have to find a 3rd party library for. The stdlib did recently get [some parallelism extensions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism) but I don't think these are what you're looking for

Comment: I considered C++11 without external libraries only. Without diving deeper into the C++17 extensions they at least seem similar to D's parallel().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no equivalent in the standard C++ library.

There probably is something similar in some 3rd party C++ library. Unfortunately I am not aware of any such library as I do not do C++ programming for over 15 years...